# need help shortening/looping javascript function using loops and alternative to mod

Tags: javascript

I have an animation that shows one of 8 possible frames depending on the scrolling position on the page. Every time you scroll 20px the next frame is shown until you get to frame 8, then it goes back to frame one after 160px. At the moment if the page is 2000px long I need 100 if statements which seems ridiculous. There must be a way to make it into a few lines using a nice function using loops. A friend said it would be a job for 'mod'but apparently javascript cant do mod or remainders.

I have done an excerpt of the script below but you can see the whole idea here

http://jsfiddle.net/jimmytheman/NnFmn/2/

```
function scroll() {

 if (window.pageYOffset < 20){

    setTimeout("document.images['ball'].src=imageArray[0].src",0);
}
else if (window.pageYOffset < 40){
    setTimeout("document.images['ball'].src=imageArray[1].src",0);
    }
else if (window.pageYOffset < 60){

    setTimeout("document.images['ball'].src=imageArray[2].src",0);
    }
else if (window.pageYOffset < 80){

    setTimeout("document.images['ball'].src=imageArray[3].src",0);
    }
```

Comment: Just a side note, do ***NOT*** pass strings to `setTimeout`.  That uses `eval` (which is `evil`).  Pass functions instead.  `setTimeout(function(){ document.images['ball'].src=imageArray[0].src; }, 0);`

Comment: thanks, I'll bear than in mind

Comment: You should not use that kind of code... for that kind of things, it's better to use sprites, like in game, because you don't need to wait for the load of images as you scroll...

Look for [that plugin](http://www.spritely.net/documentation/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulo in javascript it's `%` character, http://jsfiddle.net/NnFmn/4/

but you can shorten the code using something like this:

```
function scroll() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.images['ball'].src = imageArray[window.pageYOffset % 7].src;
    }, 0);
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NnFmn/5/